# Creating a notification system in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

so I am building the backend for a web forum using Django & Django REST Framework and would like to include a notification system.

So I have a "Discussion" Model:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
   return f'{instance.id}/{filename}'


class Discussion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_pinned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_open = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_boosted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    started_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='started_discussions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='subscribed_discussions')
    tools = models.ManyToManyField(to=Tool, related_name='belongs_to_channels', blank=True)
    channels = models.ManyToManyField(to=Channel, related_name='discussions')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} | By: {self.started_by.username} | Content: {self.title} ...'
```

and I have a "Comment" Model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(to=Discussion, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    written_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='written_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='liked_comments', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} | By: {self.written_by.username} | {self.content[0:30]} ...'
```

Basically my question is that I would like to create a functionality where if someone creates a new comment on a discussion, the users that have subscribed to this discussion will get a notification. So for example if someone comments on a discussion you are subscribed to, you'll get a notification "New Comment from {user that commented} on {discussion you're subscribed to}"

My thought was to create a new django app "Notification" with the respective model and serializer to it.. But I'm really not sure how to get started or whats the best way to implement this?

Hopefully I was able to provide enough information for someone to answer and thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have not used it, however https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications looks like it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it and see if I can use it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Django channels and websockets. When you connect to a website or make a request to it your connection to the website is actually cut short, a websocket connection keeps the TCP connection open which is perfect for sending events down to a client from the server when a specific event happens.

Django channels are Django's implementation of websockets, in Node for example uses socket.io.

I haven't used the channels in any project yet so I don't want to mislead you with something I don't know works myself but I know that what your looking for here is websockets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use django-notifications for this, you could read aboutt it from their documentation. https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications

Comment: I implemented something similar to this in a social media website i built

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32611615)